# i want to know how many processes this program actually produces

Tags: c, fork, pid

I want to know how many parent-child processes does this program is producing like by calling fork three times

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main(){  
    int i;

    printf("before fork, my pid is %d\n" , getpid());  

    for (i=0; i<3; i++){

        if ( fork()== 0 )
            printf("Hi, I am child. My pid is %d\n", getpid());
    }
}
```

output of the above program

> before fork, my pid is 4221
>
> done, my pid is 4221
>
> done, my pid is 4224
>
> done, my pid is 4223
>
> done, my pid is 4226
>
> done, my pid is 4222
>
> done, my pid is 4227
>
> done, my pid is 4225
>
> done, my pid is 4228

Comment: You can easily work this out on paper. Tip: Each `fork()` call produces a child process, and that child process continues to loop exactly as the parent will.

Comment: That's when child killers are welcome

Comment: as many as the number of "my pid"

Comment: What is your understanding on the subject?

Answer (score 1):

You can check it yourself with `pstree -p` (`p` to print PIDs)

Put a `getchar()` to pause the program:

```
for (i = 0; i < 3 ; i++)
{
    if (fork() == 0)
        printf("Hi, I am child. My pid is %d\n", getpid());
}
getchar();
```

Now open a new console and use `pstree` with the paused program using the PID of the parent process:

```
david@david:~$ pidof program
17460 17459 17458 17457 17456 17455 17454 17453
david@david:~$ pstree -p 17453
demo(17453)─┬─demo(17454)─┬─demo(17457)───demo(17459)
            │             └─demo(17458)
            ├─demo(17455)───demo(17460)
            └─demo(17456)
```